# Bot Framework Proactive Message Passing Id Into Conversation State

Tags: botframework, proactive

I have a SMS / Twilio Channel that I'm using to send out a Proactive message to the user.  To send the Proactive message I'm calling a API method passing in **MySpecialId** which is used later in the conversation.

I want to save this MySpecialId into the conversation but at the point I have the MySpecialId the conversation doesn't exist yet, and I don't have a turnContext, so I can't really save it yet.

Is there a way to pass this Id from my API method into the BotCallback?  I created a quick example.  (Here is the original example I'm using https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)

Thanks

```
        [HttpGet("{number}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string MySpecialId)
        {
            //For Twillio Channel
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("https://sms.botframework.com/");

            var NewConversation = new ConversationReference
            {
                User = new ChannelAccount { Id = $"+1{PHONENUMBERTOTEXTHERE}" },
                Bot = new ChannelAccount { Id = "+1MYPHONENUMBERHERE" },
                Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = $"+1{PHONENUMBERTOTEXTHERE}" },
                ChannelId = "sms",
                ServiceUrl = "https://sms.botframework.com/"
            };

        BotAdapter ba = (BotAdapter)_HttpAdapter;
            await ((BotAdapter)_HttpAdapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_AppId, NewConversation, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));

            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            };
        }

      private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var MyConversationState = _ConversationState.CreateProperty<MyConversationData>(nameof(MyConversationData));
                var ConversationState = await MyConversationState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new MyConversationData(), cancellationToken);

                //********************************************************************************************************************
                ConversationState.MySpecialId = //HOW DO I GET MySpecialId FROM THE GET METHOD ABOVE HERE?
                //********************************************************************************************************************

                await _ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync((turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Starting proactive message bot call back");                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this._Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can. Normally, you would do something like this by passing values through `Activity.ChannelData`, but `ChannelData` doesn't exist on `ConversationReference`.

---

Per comments below, @Ryan pointed out that you can pass data on `ConversationAccount.Properties`. Note, however, this is currently only available in the C# SDK. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/970) to bring this into the Node SDK, but ETA is unknown at this point.

---

Instead, I'd suggest using a something more native to C#, like:

1. Create a `ConcurrentDictionary`

```cs
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _idMap;
```

2. Map `MySpecialId` to `Conversation.Id` (in your Get function)

```cs
_idMap.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.Conversation.Id, MySpecialId, (key, newValue) => MySpecialId);
```

3. Access the `MySpecialId` from the `Activity.Conversation.Id` (in BotCallback)

```cs
var ConversationState = await MyConversationState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new MyConversationData(), cancellationToken);
ConversationState.MySpecialId = _idMap.GetValueOrDefault(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);
```

4. Save `ConversationState`

```cs
await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
```

There's other ways you could do this and some validation checks you'll need to add, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you - I'm just checking in the ConversationAccount class there is a property called Properties which accepts a JObject.  It's similar to what you are saying - just put a dictionary of items in there.  Is that OK to use?  It does appear to get passed down to the BotCallback method.


Thanks

Comment: I forgot about that! That actually should work. Note, however, that this [isn't in the Node version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/ConversationAccount?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) (which is fine, in your case).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much.  Just to be 100% sure, those properties only are for that conversation and don't get carried over to other conversations right?  (My testing is showing it's only for that conversation)

Thanks again.

Comment: @Ryan. Corrent. Because they're tied to the ConversationReference.